# Why static_cast can't cast ulong to uchar*

Tags: c++, winapi, bcrypt

```
BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE hAlg = nullptr; 
DWORD HashObjectSize = 0; 
ULONG CopyByte = NULL; 

status = BCryptGetProperty
        (
            hAlg,
            BCRYPT_OBJECT_LENGTH,
            (PUCHAR)&HashObjectSize, //unsigned long =?= unsigned char*
            sizeof(PUCHAR),
            &CopyByte,
            NULL
        );
```

This code works without errors, but if i change the c-style cast to static_cast I get the error

> `Invalid conversion`

DWORD is a unsigned long

PUCHAR is a unsigned char*

Why i can convert this variable with c-style cast, but can't with `static_cast(PUCHAR)&HashObjectSize`

Answer (score 2):

[`static_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) can't cast from an integer to a pointer, and vice versa.  Or between two unrelated types.

`unsigned long*` and `unsigned char*` are unrelated pointer types, so you can't `static_cast` between them, you need to use [`reinterpret_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) instead, eg:

`reinterpret_cast<PUCHAR>(&HashObjectSize)`

A [C-style cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) checks several different types of casts until one of them can be used.  It will check `reinterpret_cast` if `static_cast` can't be used:

> ( *new-type* ) *expression*   (1)
>
> ...
>
> 1. When the *C-style cast expression* is encountered, the compiler attempts to interpret it as the following cast expressions, in this order:
>
>    a) `const_cast<new-type>(expression);`
>    b) `static_cast<new-type>(expression)`, with extensions: pointer or reference to a derived class is additionally allowed to be cast to pointer or reference to unambiguous base class (and vice versa) even if the base class is inaccessible (that is, this cast ignores the private inheritance specifier). Same applies to casting pointer to member to pointer to member of unambiguous non-virtual base;
>    c) `static_cast` (with extensions) followed by `const_cast`;
>    d) `reinterpret_cast<new-type>(expression);`
>    e) `reinterpret_cast` followed by `const_cast`.
>
> The first choice that satisfies the requirements of the respective cast operator is selected, even if it cannot be compiled (see example). If the cast can be interpreted in more than one way as `static_cast` followed by a `const_cast`, it cannot be compiled.
>
> In addition, C-style cast notation is allowed to cast from, to, and between pointers to incomplete class type. If both *expression* and *new-type* are pointers to incomplete class types, it's unspecified whether `static_cast` or `reinterpret_cast` gets selected.